# Js Regex exact pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write function which exactly tell me that expression suit to regular expression.
eg.

```
<script>
var pattern = /[0-9]{2}/

alert(pattern.test("1236"));

</script>
```

This expression is true, but I want false because I want only two numbers

eg.

```
alert(pattern.test("25"));
```

Only this should be true.

How can I change my code?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]{2}$/
```

It says now:

`Two digits from start "^" to the end "$"`